# SQL Report Builder is slow with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sharepoint, report, builder

Every time we do consult with SQL Report Builder, it takes likes 15 minutes or more creating this report. The data is in an Oracle DB and we use the native connector 
(we've tried other ones too) but we need a connector for x64 because we are going to publish these reports in Sharepoint.

Comment: First, I'm guessing that you're talking about SQL Server Report Builder.  Can you give us a bit more information about what, exactly, the problem is?  Are you concerned about the time it takes to run the report query against the Oracle database and return results?  If so, what is the query?  What is the query plan?  Have you run the query against the database from a different tool?  What were the results?  Is the problem that the SQL Server Report Builder front end is slow to start up?  That it is slow to respond to certain operations?  Which operations, exactly?

Comment: If you are using Oracle reports (using developer suite) then you are using a very outdated reporting tool. Not too sure about SQL Server Report builder though.

Comment: yes we had don that with reporting using this provider msdaora.1 and with this works like a charm take like 2 minuts but the problem is that work for 32 bits and we need to work with 64 bit pleasee help

Answer (score 0):

we use a especial code for this trouble and also the server was very slow

this solve my problem 
the code is 
Omite Oracle Connection Name=True